# Laravel edit localization

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a backend for translations edit. Strictly speaking I want to let users edit the array in resources/lang/[en|it|es|pt]/something.php

Before start writing spaghetti code with fread/fwrite I would like to know if there's some Laravel way to do it.

Comment: I guess it's preferable to work with a dedicated class and the database than actually editing the files, especially if you're going to rely on user input.

Comment: Why do you think it's preferable? I don't want to change the translation mechanism, I just would like to permit the users to change translation values without working on a php file.
I was thinking using var_export  to do the trick, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution according to what inside the class proposed by Alexey Mezenin, that use var_export like my first thought. I didn't want to install an entire system to manage my translations, since I'm writing my own backend. My solution is the following (and works like a charm :)

```
public function saveTranslations(Request $request, $key) {

    $locales = LaravelLocalization::getSupportedLocales();
    foreach ($locales as $l => $lang) {
        ${"array_$l"} = Lang::get('recipes', [], $l);
        ${"array_$l"}[$key] = $request->$l;
        uksort(${"array_$l"}, "strnatcasecmp");

        $path = \App::langPath() . '/' . $l . '/recipes.php';
        $output = "<?php\n\nreturn " . var_export(${"array_$l"}, true) . ";\n";

        $f = new Filesystem();
        $f->put($path, $output);
    }

    return redirect(LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale() . '/admin/translations');
}
```

It works essentially like laravel-translation-manager (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager/blob/master/src/Manager.php#L140), but with a custom logic.

Localization is managed through mcamara/laravel-localization package.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use some package for this task. I'd use this one:
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager

> This is a package to manage Laravel translation files. It does not replace the Translation system, only import/export the php files to a database and make them editable through a webinterface.